# C++ : convert uint64_t to unsigned char array

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I need to convert for exemple this number : 281474976710655 to a unsigned char array like this one :

```
unsigned char value[6] = { 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff };
```

I try to memcpy and other techniques but i didn't get the correct value back, always random hex...

I'm not a c++ developer so thanks to explain if you can.

Thanks a lot, bye !

Comment: What values did you expect, and what did you get? And 6 bytes doesn't seem to be the proper length for a 64-bit value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C - unsigned int to unsigned char array conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10319805/c-unsigned-int-to-unsigned-char-array-conversion)

Comment: Remember to bear in mind that if you use something like memcpy then the byte order will depend on endianness...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
uint64_t x=281474976710655
unsigned char value[sizeof(x)];
std::memcpy(value,&x,sizeof(x));
```

Comment: How do you convert it back to a new uint64_t?

Comment: @thc memcpy(&x, value, sizeof(uint64_t))